# Install dlib with cuda support ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, gpu, nvidia, dlib

I have CUDA 9.0 and CUDNN 7.1 installed on Ubuntu 18.04(Linux mint 19). Tensorflow-gpu works fine on GPU(GTX 1080ti).

Now i am trying to build dlib with CUDA support:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes DLIB_USE_CUDA --clean
```

Got the error:

```
user@user-pc:~/Downloads/dlib$ sudo python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes DLIB_USE_CUDA --clean
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /home/me/Downloads/dlib/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/me/Downloads/dlib/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=yes -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=yes -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.6.5") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
-- pybind11 v2.2.2
-- Using CMake version: 3.10.2
-- Compiling dlib version: 19.15.99
-- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
-- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
-- Enabling AVX instructions
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'cblas'
--    No package 'cblas' found
-- Checking for module 'lapack'
--    No package 'lapack' found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Found Intel MKL BLAS/LAPACK library
-- Looking for sgesv
-- Looking for sgesv - found
-- Looking for sgesv_
-- Looking for sgesv_ - found
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found suitable version "9.0", minimum required is "7.5") 
-- Looking for cuDNN install...
-- Found cuDNN: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so
-- Building a CUDA test project to see if your compiler is compatible with CUDA...
-- *****************************************************************************************************************
-- *** CUDA was found but your compiler failed to compile a simple CUDA program so dlib isn't going to use CUDA. 
-- *** The output of the failed CUDA test compile is shown below: 
-- ***    Change Dir: /home/me/Downloads/dlib/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/dlib_build/cuda_test_build
    ***    
    ***    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make"
    ***    [ 50%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o
    ***    cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
    ***    CMake Error at cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o.cmake:215 (message):
    ***      Error generating
    ***      /home/me/Downloads/dlib/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/dlib_build/cuda_test_build/CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir//./cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o
    ***    
    ***    
    ***    CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o' failed
    ***    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o] Error 1
    ***    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/all' failed
    ***    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/all] Error 2
    ***    Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
    ***    make: *** [all] Error 2
    ***    
-- *****************************************************************************************************************
-- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/Downloads/dlib/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j8'
Scanning dependencies of target dlib
[  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
```

Comment: HAve you tried `sudo apt-get install g++`?

Comment: Yes. G++ is installed: g++ is already the newest version (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2).

Comment: Try to install a newer version of gcc and g++, like 6.4. It uses C++14 as default.

Comment: Thank you! Latest version of compiler is not supported. 6 version is available and compiled dlib with CUDA support. The problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 version of gcc solved the problem.

Instructions for 7 version:
https://gist.github.com/jlblancoc/99521194aba975286c80f93e47966dc5