# Dlib don't using GPU when I using tensorflow_gpu

Tags: tensorflow, dlib

I have **2 version**s of tensorflow, cpu and gpu. And I am using conda to manage my environment. When I activate the cpu's one, dlib can run on GPU very well. But When I use the gpu's one, it just run on the cpu. I don't why, please help me.

There are some of my system information, I don't know it can give some information.

- Ubuntu 18.04LTS
- python 3.6
- CUDA 10.1
- tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0
- tensorflow 1.12.0

Test code

```
conda activate ML

ipython

>>> import dlib

>>> dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA

True
```

The code above output True but the code below output False.

```
conda activate ML_GPU

ipython

>>> import dlib

>>> dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA

False
```

I hope when I using GPU version tensorflow dlib can using my GPU just like the CPU's one. Is anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had fixed this problem via install dlib manually.
There are steps to do that.

**Notice: You should do these steps on you virtual envs.**

```
conda activate ML_GPU

pip uninstall dlib

git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git

cd dlib

mkdir build

cd build

cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1

cmake --build .

cd ..

python setup.py install
```

There still have a problem When you do the last step. You should notice if you see information like this one——**CUDA was found but your compiler failed to compile a simple CUDA program so dlib isn't going to use CUDA.**

Then you should change your g++ compiler version. You also can seek some info from
[Install dlib with cuda support ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466638/install-dlib-with-cuda-support-ubuntu-18-04) .

My g++ version is :(Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026. It looks like the newest version is not compatible with CUDA.

If everything is OK, You will see

```
>>> dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA
True
```